# git diff on two remote servers (outside git git --no-index)

Tags: linux, git, bash, ssh

Is it possible to use the command git diff --no-index on two remote servers through ssh.

I want to use the output of the command git diff but on a non repository . Between two remote ssh directory .

Comment: on non repository it is not possible but between two repo it might be

Answer (score 0):

I've never bridged a diff command across servers, but effectively...you'd just be using `diff`.  `git diff` uses whatever system-specified `diff` tool you have available to compare different versions, and since `--no-index` would allow you to compare across non-versioned files, `diff` is your best bet.

Comment: yes but i'm looking to use git diff because i want to use this lib https://diff2html.xyz/ who needs an ouput from git diff

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to conform to the demands of the library then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# Get the working tree from repo 1:
git archive --format=zip --remote=ssh://<user>@<host>/repo1/<repo1 name> <tag or HEAD> > archive1.zip

# Get the working tree from repo 2:
git archive --format=zip --remote=ssh://<user>@<host>/repo2/<repo2 name> <tag or HEAD> > archive2.zip

mkdir tmpdir tmpdir2
(cd tmpdir; git init .)

# Unzip archive1 into tmpdir, make a temporary git repo out of it:
(cd tmpdir; unzip ../archive1.zip ; git add .; git commit -a -m "archive1")

# Move the .git directory to tmpdir2:
mv tmpdir/.git tmpdir2

# Unzip archive2 into tmpdir2, and compare:
(cd tmpdir2; unzip ../archive2.zip ; git diff ) > git-diff.txt

# Cleanup:
rm -rf tmpdir tmpdir2 archive1.zip archive2.zip
```